# Asp.Net Core HTML Helper does not select the value it is provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a Select List to my view. In the razor template I have:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProjectRecordGroupParsed)
{
    <div>
        <!-- Code: @item.Code -->
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectRecordGroup", new SelectList(AllProjectRecordGroups, "Code", "Name", item.Code), "Select Project Record Group", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

The result of this is a drop down with the values from AllProjectRecordGroup which does contain this option:

```
<option value="MARKPROJECT">MARK Project</option>
```

and the comment line contains this:

```
<!-- Code: MARKPROJECT -->
```

So, I am wondering what is going on here? Why is the value not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, I had to change this line to make the ID unique:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectRecordGroup", new SelectList(
```

It now works with this change:

```
@Html.DropDownList($"ProjectRecordGroup{item.Code}", new SelectList(
```

Answer (score 0):

where **AllProjectRecordGroups** come from, if i understood this class populating this selectbox right?? maybe you need return this from controller with data, give more details please, and i trying help you

Comment: Yes, as noted in my post, the options are populated from AllProjectRecordGroups and I can find the option with the value specified.

Comment: you need pass a SelectList from controller and in view you convert for IEnumerable<SelectListItem>selectListFromController, try this and reply if works please